# Accessing Mongoose schema object from Express 3 routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mongoose

How do I expose MongooseSchema objects set in app.js to the routes?

I get this error when trying to use a variable set in **app.js** from **routes/index.js**. I've been using node for just a few months, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Please note I am using **Express v3.3.4**

```
500 ReferenceError: ProfileSchema is not defined
```

In my **app.js** file I have:

```
var express = require('express')
  , util = require('util')
  , Promise = require('bluebird')
  , crypto = require('crypto')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var ProfileSchema = require('./models/schemas').ProfileSchema;

/*** ..... ***/

app.get('/user/home', routes.user_home);
```

And in my **/routes/index.js** I have:

```
exports.user_home = function(req, res){
    //foo
}
```

I would like to do this inside of that **user_home** route:

```
ProfileSchema.find({ users: 'joeblow' }, function (err, docs) {});
```

But the ReferenceError is thrown, since ProfileSchema is not accesible to the route.

**NOTE: I can use ProfileSchema.find() from app.js just fine.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `ProfileSchema` is only defined in **app.js**, but **app.js** and **/routes/index.js** do *not share the same scope* !

This might be confusing at first, because it's different from client-side JavaScript, but you should take a few minutes to carefully read [Node.js docs regarding globals](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html).
Quoting from the docs,

> *In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a global variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside a Node module will be **local to that module**.*

To fix your issue, you have two solutions

- You can either require your `ProfileSchema` directly from
  **/routes/index.js**

  ```
  var ProfileSchema = require('./models/schemas').ProfileSchema;

  exports.user_home = function(req, res){
      //ProfileSchema is defined ! Hurray !
  }
  ```
- Or, if you still want to require `ProfileSchema` in **app.js**, you
  need to do something that is called *dependency injection*, which a
  complicated word for saying you need to pass your `ProfileSchema`
  variable to **/routes/index.js**. One way to do that is to export a
  function in **/routes/index.js** that will take `ProfileSchema` as a
  parameter. So you would need to change your code to :

  ```
  exports.user_home = function(ProfileSchema){
     return function(req, res){
      //ProfileSchema is defined ! Hurray !
    }
  }
  ```

  And you would pass the parameter in **app.js** like so :

  ```
  var ProfileSchema = require('./models/schemas').ProfileSchema;
  app.get('/user/home', routes.user_home(ProfileSchema));
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Couldn't I also put the variable in **routes/index** like this: `var ProfileSchema = module.exports.ProfileSchema = require('./models/schemas').ProfileSchema;` to pass it back up to app.js? That way they both have access to it?

Comment: @taco Yes of course, they will both have access to it. You can *require your module in both files*, *in one file and export it to the other* or *vice-versa*. It's totally up to you. Just try to *stick as much as possible* to the rule you chose in your entire app (eg. requiring a module when you need it & avoiding dependency injection, or only requiring modules in `app.js` and injecting them in your controllers etc...), that will save you some headaches.

Comment: Thanks again, Waldo. I'd seen people export like that before, but it all didn't click until you explained the solution.